# Is Athelas guarded by Forest Grove

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings-lcg

A Journey to Rhosgobel actually has an interesting scenario where you can **add** Athelas to the staging area. Is it guarded when added by Forest Grove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not guarded when added by Forest Grove.

According to the FAQs, on **guarded**:

> Surge, Doomed, and Guarded keywords should be resolved any time the card on which they occur is revealed from the encounter deck, including during setup.

The word **revealed** here is not mentioned in the actual rule book and is the cause for confusion. If we assume that Guarded is only triggered when a card is **revealed** then Athelas enters the staging area unguarded when added by Forest Grove.

Comment: Note that this has also gotten [an official answer from Caleb Grace](https://community.fantasyflightgames.com/topic/90045-i-believe-that-everybody-is-wrong-about-forest-groveajtr/#entry876304), the designer of the game. He wrote: "Because the Athelas is not revealed when you trigger the Response of Forest Grove, you place an unguarded Athelas in the staging area." So this question has been officially answered.